# replacing value of a column(unknown length) with substring

Tags: mysql, sql, string

How can I replace the value(unknown length) of a column in mySQL workbench with a substring that exists in that column?

For ex:
If I have the value of a column like "ABC.123.Chrome/123", how do I replace this for all rows with just "Chrome/123"?  I want to replace value in that string of unknown length with everything that comes after Chrome only.

Comment: Is the 123 in Chrome/123 variable as well?  Also, do you care about performance or is it just a 1 time deal?

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you want to include Chrome:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET ColumnName = SUBSTRING(ColumnName,LOCATE('Chrome'))
WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%Chrome%'
```

Comment: You'd probably want to use a LIKE in the WHERE I think:
WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%Chrome%'